# nodes write the same value on all plots

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I am struggling with a feature I would like to add to a plot : write a value associated to each plot. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\TracSecReso}[4]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Wr{#2*sqrt(1-2*(#3^2))} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\GdBWr{(20*log10(#1))-10*(log10((1-(\Wr/#2)^2)^2+4*(#3^2)*(\Wr/#2)^2))}
    \addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(\Wmin,\GdBWr) (\Wr,\GdBWr) } [densely dotted,#4]
     node[pos=0.5,above] {\GdBWr};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[ymax=50,ymin=-40]
                \TracSecReso{1}{1}{0.5}{}
                \TracSecReso{10}{1}{0.05}{}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiled it gives:

[image]

As you can see, there are two different horizontal lines on the picture, each should have its value indicated on it, but the same value appears on the two lines.

I've tried several ways, I can't get around that, can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the way `pgfplots` surveys and expands things. One way to fix it is to use the `\edef\temp\noexpand` trick from section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the manual v1.16.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand*{\TracSecReso}[4]{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Wr{#2*sqrt(1-2*(#3^2))} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\GdBWr{(20*log10(#1))-10*(log10((1-(\Wr/#2)^2)^2+4*(#3^2)*(\Wr/#2)^2))}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot [mark=none] coordinates {(\Wmin,\GdBWr) (\Wr,\GdBWr) } [densely dotted,#4]
     node[pos=0.5,above] {\GdBWr};}
     \temp
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
        \def\Wmin{10^(-1)}
        \begin{semilogxaxis}[ymax=50,ymin=-40]
                \TracSecReso{1}{1}{0.5}{}
                \TracSecReso{10}{1}{0.05}{}
        \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]